# show image tiles from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, deepzoom, seadragon

I am trying to build an asp.net web application (not using Silverlight) which zooms and pans into large images like Seadragon. But I do not like to use the deepzoom composer tool to create this files and store the tiles in some folder structure in my server. I would like to store them in a database. There is an Article here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33146/Silverlight-Database-Deep-Zoom which describes very nicely how to do this for the Silverlight version of the deepzoom with multiscaleimage control. My Idea is to achieve something similar but without Silverlight.

Maybe My question is similar to this [The correct choice of tools for a new Deep Zoom application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641556/the-correct-choice-of-tools-for-a-new-deep-zoom-application), I need your suggestions on how to build a control which can show the tiles from database.

Comment: Hi, did you found some solution to get image tiles from db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question about creating the tiles and storing them in the database? Or is it assuming you already have that, and wondering how best to display them?

If the latter, I recommend OpenSeadragon:

http://openseadragon.github.io/

You just need to write a custom tilesource to produce URLs for the tiles:

http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-custom/

Comment: Hi @iangilman
Are there possibility to store images tiles in database and openseadragon use them?

Comment: Sure. You would need to provide an API for it to get the tiles from the database. OpenSeadragon supports a number of formats, each of which expect the tiles to be arranged in a certain order; your API could mimic one of those formats. Or if you already have an API, you can write a custom "tile source" that would utilize that API. Keep in mind that databases aren't necessarily built for storing large things like images; a file server like Amazon's S3 might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know seadragon or deepzoom but in GIS applications with the help of GeoServer (free) you can serve big raster images with tiled-WMS (web map service).

Please google geoserver and wms-t keywords to check if they are suitable for your project or not.